# Can you back-transform standard errors from log-transformed data?

Tags: data-transformation, standard-error, back-transformation

I fit a model with transformed data with log10 transformation. I would like to report the results using the original scale and not the transformed means. I know you can back transform the log means by taking 10 and raising it to the power of the log-mean. I would also like to have the standard error back-transformed. Is this possible and can you do it the same way as for means? What about confidence intervals?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Calculating standard error after a log-transform](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/123514/calculating-standard-error-after-a-log-transform) [This question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/33382/28500) deals more directly with the confidence interval issue, and [this question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/589920/28500) provides more links and discusses alternative approaches to log transformation.

Comment: Also, note that if you "back transform the log means by taking 10 and raising it to the power of the log-mean" you are estimating the _geometric mean_ of the original data, not the usual arithmetic mean.